# Completion by fuzzy search in large dictionary file, displaying candidates inline

Tags: completion, search

What would be the best (simplest, with minimal latency) way to load a large dictionary file (about 2M terms; plain text, one term per line), and then do (repeatedly, on a keystroke) a fuzzy search, with the candidates displayed inline?

The search can be started after the fist search token has been typed (like with completion-at-point-functions) or ab initio.

Something like fzf or ivy? But I cannot figure out how to read plain text from a particular file and keep it in memory.

**Clarification**: there is *a ton* of packages doing various flavors of completion and presenting the results in the **minibuffer** (and some also open an annoying helper window at the top of the frame). Those are not the droids I am looking for. I would like to see my completion candidates **inline** (at point): a dynamic list being displayed immediately under the query as it is typed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would do, using the 466544-strong `words.txt` file from [english-words](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words) as an example:

```el
(defun my-dictionary ()
  "Return hash-table whose keys comprise words.txt."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents "/path/to/english-words/words.txt")
    (let ((table (make-hash-table :test #'equal :size 466544)))
      (while (not (eobp))
        (puthash (buffer-substring (point) (line-end-position)) nil table)
        (forward-line))
      table)))

(defvar my-dictionary
  (lazy-completion-table my-dictionary my-dictionary)
  "Lazy completion table for function `my-dictionary'.")
```

The basic idea is that you read and cache the contents of your dictionary file into a data structure (a [hash-table](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hash-Tables.html) in my example) which standard completion functions such as `completing-read` and `completion-in-region` can understand. The benefit of this is that you can pick and choose between minibuffer and in-buffer completion, as well as from many conforming completion frameworks, using the same completion collection. See [`(elisp) Completion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Basic-Completion.html) for more information on this.

After that, you can pass the lazy (cached) collection to whichever conforming completion frontend tickles your fancy. With `ivy-mode` enabled, for example, a call to

```el
(completion-in-region START END my-dictionary)
```

for some [buffer positions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Positions.html) `START` and `END` will perform an in-place in-buffer completion like the one you describe.

---

Here is a more concrete example which completes in-buffer the word preceding point:

```el
(defun my-complete-word-in-region ()
  "Complete word preceding point under `my-dictionary'."
  (interactive)
  (completion-in-region
   (save-excursion
     (skip-syntax-backward "w")
     (point))
   (point)
   my-dictionary))
```

You could then bind this to some convenient key.

---

If the dictionary file you want to read in does not change very often, you can speed up the initial hash-table-creation latency of the function `my-dictionary` by creating the hash-table and writing its [printed representation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Read-and-Print.html) to some auxiliary file ahead of time, and then reading that auxiliary file as Lisp instead, though it may not be worth the effort, given a subsequent caching of the hash-table in memory and the inherent latency of fuzzy completion.

See also [issue #1174](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/1174) for some `ivy`-specific performance tips.

Comment: ... is there a way to do this starting from something other than a prefix? So it would not be "completion" as such, but general fuzzy search in the dictionary set of strings. Or perhaps starting from a zero-length prefix that matches everything in the dictionary, and then narrowing things down.

Comment: @Dmitri `ivy-mode`, as well as other completion frontends such as Helm (maybe Ido and Icicles as well? not sure), already support this. Even the built-in `completion-styles` aren't restricted to prefix completion, depending on the style used. The built-in styles just aren't as fuzzy as, say, Ivy.

Comment: @Dmitri For example, enable `ivy-mode` and then invoke the sample command `my-complete-word-in-region` with point placed after some whitespace, i.e. with no word preceding point. This will instigate in-buffer Ivy completion over the entire dictionary, without any prefix. Typing any number of space-delimited substrings, whether prefix, suffix or otherwise, will narrow the completion candidates in a fuzzy manner. Note that Ivy supports multiple types of fuzzy regexp generation, as well as ad-hoc cycling between them.

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks for pointing it out! Really cool.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, to me. But I'm guessing that this might help.

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) you can search using various kinds of fuzzy matching.

[Icicles search](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) treats search hits as completion candidates, and Icicles lets you use [fuzzy matching](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Completion_Methods_and_Styles#FuzzyMatchCompletion) for completion.

As a perhaps related (unclear from your question) approach, library [Synonyms](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Synonyms) ([`synonyms.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/synonyms.el)) uses a large (24MB) thesaurus file. You can query for synonyms of a term, using completion. If you use Icicles then the completion matching can be fuzzy (again, any of several kinds of fuzzy - au choix, changeable anytime while querying/completing).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if my question is unclear. If you could name one particular aspect, I could try to improve the question. icicles and Synonyms are relevant but do not fit exactly, as they display candidate matches in the minibuffer only (so far as I can see). I need completion at point, as in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMQFqqZeorc and generally similar to modern IDEs.